# IONIC 4 Online/Offline sync from SQLite to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, angular, typescript, sqlite, ionic4

I am about to start working on an IONIC app that requires data to be stored on the users' device (SQLite) and accessible when the app is not online. The app will also need to sync any changes made on the local storage to the server DB (SQL Server) and vice versa when an internet connection is available.

What is the best/recommended way to accomplish this task?

Comment: The best way is to simply search the internet first. This sort of question is both far too broad and requires an opinion - what is "best" for you is not necessarily "best" for anyone else. Recommendations are also off-topic. Again - try searching first.

Comment: @SMor Thanks for the feedback. I spent a lot of time researching this topic, and most of the solutions/recommendations I came across are for a non-relation (NoSQL) databases. The application that I am planning to write needs to work with an existing relational database.